# What is "SPIislatency" in response headers of SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

Can you please explain what is the use of `SPIislatency` in response headers of SharePoint Online. I am trying to understand the performance tuning concepts of SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SPIislatency` is the time in milliseconds taken in the front-end Web server after the request has been received the front-end Web server, but before the Web Application begins processing the request.

This value is stored in partitioned tables for the `RequestUsage` logging provider. This view can be queried to return data pertaining to all client web requests that have been made since the beginning of the retention period.

As per my understanding Response Headers can only be removed using an `HttpModule`. Since its SharePoint Online that option is not feasible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I totally agree that we can modify or remove since its online version.

Comment: I wanted to comment on this in case anyone finds their way here while searching. SPIisLatency is only one metric to understanding page performance and tuning. There are others. For a breakdown of the metrics and what they mean, I'll refer you to my blog post on the topic: https://sharepointinterface.com/2017/07/07/the-five-minute-page-performance-troubleshooting-guide-for-sharepoint-online/. Also, the Page Diagnostics Tool for SharePoint provides access to these performance metrics: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-diagnostics-for-shar/inahogkhlkbkjkkaleonemeijihmfagi?hl=en